# If $f\left( x \right) =\sin\log _e\left( \frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{1-x} \right) $ then find the range of this function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Problem :

If $f\left( x \right) =\sin\log _e\left( \frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{1-x} \right) $ then find the range of this function.

My approach :

$\frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{1-x} >0 \Rightarrow 1-x >0 $ also $4-x^2 >0$

$\Rightarrow x \in (-2,1)$ Domain of f(x) is (-2,1)

Now how to find the range of  this function please suggest on this .. thanks..

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$\lim_{x\to -2^+}\frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{1-x}=0\;\;,\;\;\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{1-x}=\infty$$

and thus

$$\left\{\alpha\in\Bbb R\;;\;\alpha=\log\frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{1-x}\;,\;\;x\in(-2,1)\right\}=\Bbb R$$

and from here

$$\text{Im}\left(\sin\log\frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{1-x}\right)=[-1,1]$$

Comment: but answer is (-1, sin1)

Comment: Then either "the answer" is wrong or I am.  Unless shown some mistake in the above I'm going to go for "they are wrong and I am right".

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle \frac{4-x^2}{(1-x)^2}=y$

$\displaystyle \implies 4-x^2=y(1+x^2-2x)\iff x^2(y+1)-(2y)x+y-4=0$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant $\displaystyle (2y)^2-4(y+1)(y-4)=4+3y\ge0\iff y\ge-\frac43$

$\displaystyle\implies \frac{4-x^2}{(1-x)^2}\ge-\frac43$

As we need $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{1-x}>0,$ from the above argument it can assume any positive real value

So, the range will be the range $\sin y$ for real $y$

Comment: (1-x) and not $(1-x)^2$ ...

Comment: @sultan, I have found the range of the square of $$\frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{1-x}$$

Comment: but answer is (-1,sin1)...